# Branch.io quicklink TEST has different data from LIVE

Tags: ios, branch.io

Why is it the data that I get from Branch.io's quicklinks from this method in my `didFinishLaunching` in `AppDelegate` differs from **TEST** to **LIVE** environment?

```
// Branch.io
let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
    if error == nil, let params = params {
        let jsonObj = JSON(params)
        self.handleDeeplink(jsonObj)
    }
})
```

**TEST:**

```
{
  "+non_branch_link" : "https:\/\/project-name-alternate.test-app.link\/5FACVDbDLT?__branch_flow_type=viewapp&__branch_flow_id=617351215055680480&__branch_mobile_deepview_type=1",
  "+clicked_branch_link" : false,
  "+is_first_session" : false
}
```

**LIVE:**

```
{
  "$marketing_title" : "boomboom6380",
  "vendorId" : "6380",
  "+match_guaranteed" : true,
  "~feature" : "marketing",
  "~channel" : "Email",
  "~id" : 598329481362959444,
  "+is_first_session" : false,
  "+click_timestamp" : 1548426747,
  "~creation_source" : 1,
  "$og_description" : "My OG Description",
  "~marketing" : true,
  "~campaign" : "Promo",
  "~referring_link" : "https:\/\/project-name-alternate.app.link\/KMX1mdcwmS?__branch_flow_type=viewapp&__branch_flow_id=617353403347935401&__branch_mobile_deepview_type=1",
  "+clicked_branch_link" : true,
  "$one_time_use" : false
}
```

Seems the data from the quicklinks in **TEST** env is always incomplete and says `non_branch_link`. I'm expecting my own "data" or "parameter" `vendorId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you are initializing the Branch SDK with your test branch key when clicking your test link?

If you initialize the SDK with the live key and click a test link, this is a typical response you will get.

Comment: What I can confirm is that I have the correct keys in my info.plist. No such kind of intialization code in AppDelegate.

Comment: @Glenn Did you enable test mode by calling the method Branch.setUseTestBranchKey(true)? You will need to call this before you initialize the SDK.

Comment: That's the fix! :) Thank you! I'm now calling that safely in a condition, set only yes if build is not production.